# Problema con tipos de datos en una consulta MySQL dentro de php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo este archivo php para agregar datos a una base de datos remota.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $descpremio=$_POST['descpremio'];
    $ptospremio=$_POST['ptospremio'];

    require_once 'conexion.php';
    $sqlpremio="INSERT INTO premios(descpremio,ptospremio)VALUES('$descpremio','$ptospremio')";


    if(mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)){
        $response["success"]="1";
        $response["message"]="success"; 
        echo json_encode($response);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }else{
        $response["success"]="0";
        $response["message"]="error";
        echo json_encode($response);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }
}
?>
```

En otro archivo de resgistro me funciona perfecto, solo he cambiado los campos de la base de datos y me sale un errorcomo este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el problema viene en la consulta porque el campo descpremio es un VARCHAR y el campo ptospremio es un INT. En este caso no se como realizar la query para que me de un resultado positivo y me registre los datos. ¿Alguien puede indicarme como sería esa consulta para diferentes tipos de dato?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema no tiene que ver con los tipos de datos de los campos de la tabla, sino con:

- Los índices del `$_POST`, que probablemente hayas definido con otros `name` en el `<form>`, y
- La variable `$sqlpremio` que después llamas `$sql`

Con que unifiques nombres, en ambos casos, lo solucionas

Puedes obtener más detalles haciendo:

```
echo $sqlpremio;
```

E introduciendo ese SQL directamente en phpMyAdmin a ver qué te dice el servidor MySQL

Comment: Gracias! ese era uno de los errores. Aun así me sigue entrando en el else y no me realiza el registro. Sigue saliendo {"success":"0","message":"error"}.

Comment: Ok, amplío respuesta

Comment: @MarisaCastañoLopez ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, por cuestiones de seguridad, solo comentarte que deberías estudiar el hacer "consultas preparadas" para evitar la inyección sql.

Una vez claro esto, en lo que se refiere al código:

Las dos primeras advertencias se refieren a las variables $descpremio y $ptospremio y suelen ser debidas a que intentas acceder a un índice de un array que no ha sido definido.

Mira en el formulario del HTML que existan los campos "descpremio" y "ptospremio" y que se llamen exáctamente igual en ambos sitios, de lo contrario no podrán ser obtenidos en PHP.

La tercera advertencia: "Undefined variable: sql in ..." se refiere justo a lo que dice, sin más.
No has definido la variable denominada $sql, fíjate que a la variable de la consulta la llamas $sqlpremio sin embargo después la denominas $sql.
Cambia el nombre a una de las dos.
Esto probablemente eliminará también el último error que dice que recibe una consulta vacía, lo cual es cierto porque $sql no existe, la consulta está en $sqlpremio.

Comment: Nada como enviar una respuesta y ver que mientras escribía ya han respondido :-)

Comment: Además hemos coincidido punto por punto :)

Comment: Gracias! El tema de los nombres lo he solucionado y los he unificado. Aun asi me sigue saliendo el error y no me realizala query. En el codigo que tengo de registro de usuarios, haciendo exactamente el mismo codigo con sus campos correspondientes, me funciona perfecto.                                                                                         
No estoy muy familiarizada con esto de php, por eso no realizo las consultas preparadas...

Comment: ¿No será que en la base de datos has llamado a los campos de otra forma?

Comment: se llaman exactamente igual. tengo como columnas idpremio (INT AUTOINCREMENT), descpremio (VARCHAR), ptospremio (INT), idpadre, idhijo. He leido alguna solucion que podria ser por el tipo de dato, pero no estoy segura.

Comment: Vale, si el dato es de tipo entero quita las comillas simples en la consulta a la variable del tipo entero ptospremio. Prueba y dinos que tal. VALUES ('$descpremio',$ptospremio)";

Comment: Perfecto. funciona. Gracias